# Is Nikon AF 70-300/4.0-5.6 G Black Nikkor Lens compatible with Nikon D80?

Tags: lens, nikon, compatibility, nikon-d80

I'm looking at the [Nikon AF 70-300/4.0-5.6 G Black Nikkor Lens](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00005Y3OM), and that page says that it's not compatible with Nikon D40, D40x, D60 and D5000. I'm not sure - would it work with my D80?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it will work. Those cameras don't feature an in body focus motor and won't autofocus with any "AF" lens.  Your D80 should be fine with any AF or newer AF-S lens.

Answer (score 1):

Your D80 is compatible with all Nikkor lenses produced since 1977. It has a Nikon F-mount and this is  compatible to some degree with all lenses utilizing the Nikon F-mount, produced since 1959. Lenses (of various manufacturers, not just Nikon) produced prior to 1977 can still be used after modifications. As long as Nikon does not pursue a new mount, all future Nikon lenses will also be compatible with your camera.

Comment: "Compatible" is kind of the loose term.  Its entirely possible for Nikon to add a feature to future lenses without changing the physical mount but still require something on the camera (thats effectively what the focus motor body is).

Comment: Compatible is not really that loose a term - an incompatible lens will not let you take a photo adequately at all - like a Nikkor G lens on a film camera since you won't be able to set aperture at all, a compatible lens will allow you to take photos even if you may not get to use all of its features. You'll be able to meter with the F-mount lenses I stated above  and you'll be able to set aperture and shutter speed, so I'd consider anything else to be extras, not a matter of compatibility. As it is, I actually find that Amazon should have written "Won't autofocus" instead of incompatible.